# windows permission error running uvicorn in command prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, fastapi, windowserror

So, I am newbie. I have Anaconda. I used CMD.exe (available in navigator) to install uvicorn and fastapi as given in [official tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/). then did as given in [first steps](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/). But output is not as expected.
Output is

```
(base) PS C:\Users\HP> uvicorn fasttest:app --reload
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['C:\\Users\\HP']
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Uvicorn running on ←[1mhttp://127.0.0.1:8000←[0m (Press CTRL+C to quit)
error walking file system: PermissionError [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data'
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Started reloader process [←[36m←[1m10672←[0m] using ←[36m←[1mwatchgod←[0m
←[33mWARNING←[0m:  The --reload flag should not be used in production on Windows.
←[31mERROR←[0m:    Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "fasttest".
error walking file system: PermissionError [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Application data is by default a hidden folder and a user will not have access to it.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cusersdiskapplication-data-is-not-accessible/63159b50-efba-4941-a6d0-7e58d1ccba9c

Comment: Did you try running cmd.exe in administrator mode?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Fortunately, I found a simple solution.
Run this from `cmd.exe`:

```
python -m uvicorn fasttest:app --reload
```